# Button Press Handling win32 c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, button, win32gui

I'm creating a plugin which loads a native `window` with 2 buttons, on press they should make a message box pop-up but there's no pup-up

***Creating a thread for the message loop***

```
    //create message thread
class startMessageThreadLoop
{
public:
    static DWORD WINAPI StaticThreadStart(void* Param)
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"StaticThreadStart", L"StaticThreadStart", 0);
        startMessageThreadLoop* This = (startMessageThreadLoop*)Param;
        return This->ThreadStart();
    }

    DWORD ThreadStart(void)
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"ThreadStart", L"ThreadStart", 0);
        //create message loop for buttons
        MSG msg = { 0 };
        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
        {
            //translate and send messages
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    void startMyThread()
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"startMyThread", L"startMyThread", 0);
        DWORD ThreadID;
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, StaticThreadStart, (void*) this, 0, &ThreadID);
        char szTest[100];
        printf(szTest, "%d", ThreadID);
        MessageBox(hWnd, LPCWSTR(szTest), L"ThreadIDBaby", 0);
    }
};
```

***Starting the thread***

```
startMessageThreadLoop ThreadLoopInstance;

ThreadLoopInstance.startMyThread();
```

***Creating the window***

```
vidUploader.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

vidUploader.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
vidUploader.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
vidUploader.cbClsExtra = 0;
vidUploader.cbWndExtra = 0;
vidUploader.hInstance = hUpload;
vidUploader.hIcon = LoadIcon(hUpload, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_P2GOVIDEOUPLOADER20));
vidUploader.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
vidUploader.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
vidUploader.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_P2GOVIDEOUPLOADER20);
vidUploader.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)(L"UploadVideo");
vidUploader.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcexUpload.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

RegisterClassEx(&vidUploader);

hInst = hUpload; // Store instance handle in our global variable

hWnd = CreateWindow((LPCWSTR)(L"UploadVideo"), (LPCWSTR)(L"Upload Video's"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 100, NULL, NULL, hUpload, NULL);
```

***Handle Button***

```
 LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDC_SELECT_VIDEO) {
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"Heeey", L"Hoi", 0);
        }
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

***Creating buttons & show Window***

```
SelectVideoBTN = CreateWindow(
    L"BUTTON",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
    L"Select Video's",      // Button text 
    WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles 
    10,         // x position 
    460,        // y position 
    100,        // Button width
    25,         // Button height
    hWnd,       // Parent window
    (HMENU)IDC_SELECT_VIDEO, // Assign appropriate control ID
    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
    NULL);      // Pointer not needed.

UploadBTN = CreateWindow(
    L"BUTTON",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
    L"Upload",      // Button text 
    WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles 
    390,         // x position 
    460,         // y position 
    100,        // Button width
    25,        // Button height
    hWnd,     // Parent window
    NULL,       // No menu.
    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
    NULL);      // Pointer not needed.

RECT rect = { 0, 0, uploadWNDWidth, uploadWNDHeight };
AdjustWindowRect(&rect, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE), FALSE);
SetWindowPos(hWnd, 0, 0, 0, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE);

if (!hWnd)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"), _T("Win32 Guided Tour"), NULL);

    return 1;
}

MSG msg;

// The parameters to ShowWindow explained:
// hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow
//nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain
ShowWindow(hWnd,
    nCmdShowUpload);

UpdateWindow(hWnd);
```

I believe that I'm doing everything that I have to in order to get the buttons to work, I have a message loop in a thread, I'm registering & handling the buttons and window, what am I missing?

Comment: "it doesn't quite work" is not very helpful. What is not working?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but is the window created in a different thread than the thread where you run the message loop? Because message loops have to be processed in the creation thread.

Comment: yeah I'm creating the window in a different thread, so both should be in the same thread, does that go for the button aswell?

Comment: Not sure, but there wouldn't really be a point to creating the window in thread 1, creating buttons in thread 2, and then processing the messages again in thread 1.

Comment: All GUI components in Windows are virtualized per thread. Each thread has its own message queue and input queue. All message processing must happen on the thread, that created a window (colloquially speaking, the thread owns the window). You should also avoid spreading window hierarchies across multiple threads.

Comment: Alright, thank you ^^ I'll move my code into thread 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message queue of a window is linked to the thread in which the window was created. The message loop must be processed in the same thread.

Comment: is there any other way to implement a Message Loop into my plugin? I'm creating a plugin, but the issue I have is that if I do it in my main program, it stalls everything & the main UI of the program won't load because the plugin is stuck in the while loop

Comment: You could use `PeekMessage`. It works like `GetMessage`, except that it returns instead of blocking when there are no more messages available.

Comment: and that would not require a while loop?

Comment: It would, but it will return FALSE instead of blocking your application when there are no more messages. Example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/38860/

Comment: @JonathanPotter no my previous question was about it not working, when people gave me tips about using the message loop which I forgot, in this case I didn't forget anything I just didn't know that everything had to be done in the same thread

Comment: @Hedanito I've changed it to the PeekMessage, but the only issue is that it still doesn't see my button presses